# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I just cloned a project from git, everyting ok, when i enter to a module name kardex i found this error, the thing is that this error only appears to me in my project, not happen in another cloned project from my team. I upgrade my project, compile and delete cache but not works, thanks for the help.

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Arkix\kardex\Controller\Adminhtml\Inventory\Index::__construct() must be an  
instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in  C:\laragon\www\babalu\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in  C:\laragon\www\babalu\app\code\Arkix\Kardex\Controller\Adminhtml\Inventory\Index.php:23   
Stack trace:  
#0 C:\laragon\www\babalu\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(93): Arkix\kardex\Controller\Adminhtml\Inventory\Index->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))   
#1 C:\laragon\www\babalu\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Arkix\\Kardex\\Co...', Array)   
#2 C:\laragon\www\babalu\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Arkix\\Kardex\\Co in C:\laragon\www\babalu\app\code\Arkix\Kardex\Controller\Adminhtml\Inventory\Index.php on line 23
```

this is my controller, i´m using magento 2.1, the error appears in the line 23 but i don´t know.

```
<?php

namespace Arkix\kardex\Controller\Adminhtml\Inventory;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Kardex'), __('Kardex'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Kardex'), __('Kardex'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Kardex'));

        return $resultPage;
    }

     /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Arkix_Kardex::kardex_inventory');
    }
}
```

Comment: remove/rename generated folder at magento's root.

Comment: You namespace has a misspelling

Answer (score 0):

it was caused by you modify construct of that controller.
Use command compile to solve it:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I upgrade my project, compile and delete cache but not works.

Comment: can you tell me version magento2? also, please add your controller in here to view.

Answer (score 0):

This is my controller, i´m using magento 2.1, the error appears in the line 23 but i don´t know.

```
<?php

namespace Arkix\kardex\Controller\Adminhtml\Inventory;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Kardex'), __('Kardex'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Kardex'), __('Kardex'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Kardex'));

        return $resultPage;
    }

     /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Arkix_Kardex::kardex_inventory');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change namespace from:

```
namespace Arkix\kardex\Controller\Adminhtml\Inventory;
```

to:

```
namespace Arkix\Kardex\Controller\Adminhtml\Inventory;
```

Comment: i´m going to try out your suggestion Siarhey, thanks for answer.